# copy the content of many file to one file

Tags: linux

I have many files and I want to copy the content of these files in one file. 
how to do that using linux command.

Exemple :

```
folder1\text1.txt
folder1\text2.txt
folder1\text3.txt
folder1\text5.txt
folder1\text4.txt
folder1\text6.txt
etc
```

copy the contents of all file into `folder1\text.txt`

thank

Comment: \ and linux don't go very well together...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do

```
cat folder1/text*.txt > folder1/text.txt
```

It will get all files matching `folder1/text*.txt` pattern and put its content in `folder1/text.txt`.

Note I used `folder/text.txt`, that is, forward slash. Backslash is not used in *NIX.

Comment: there could be a slight problem with this: `folder1/text*.txt` also matches `folder1/text.txt`, so there could be an unexpected behaviour if you execute the command and `text.txt` already exists.

Comment: the same command used when the file name is like this 
ERT_list.txt ; VBR_list; SFR_list etc ...  ?

Comment: Good point, @blue. In this case it would be better to use `cat text[0-9].txt`.

Comment: In that case, @EllouzeAnis, you can use `cat *_list.txt > ...`

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
find  folder1  -name  "text.*.txt"  -type  f  -exec  cat {} >>  folder1/text.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

when in folder type in command line
`cat *.txt >> text.txt`

Comment: The accepted answer is better. With this command, `cat` will read the output file at some point and append its contents to itself (i.e. duplicating some portion of the output).